# How to get Gradle to fail tests on certain console output

Tags: gradle

I am trying to configure Gradle to fail a test upon detecting a particular console output, but only if that test did not already fail.

For better context, I am trying to fail a test whenever the word `"LEAK"` is logged to the console, which Netty will [automatically log](https://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html#troubleshooting-buffer-leaks).

My current solution looks like this:

```
ext {
    testsWithLeak = [:]
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    onOutput { test, output ->
        if (output.message.contains("LEAK")) {
            testsWithLeak[test] = output.message
        }
    }

    afterTest { test, result ->
        if (result.getResultType().equals(TestResult.ResultType.FAILURE)) {
            testsWithLeak.remove(test);
        }
    }

    finalizedBy 'checkLeaks'
}

task checkLeaks {
    dependsOn 'test'
    doLast {
        testsWithLeak.each{entry ->
            throw new GradleException("ERROR: $entry.key produced leak: $entry.value")
        }
    }
}
```

This mostly works, and will correctly fail a build upon detecting a `"LEAK"` message. The problem is that since the test itself is considered a `SUCCESS`, it appears to be cached and not run again of subsequent builds. I tried calling `cleanTest` as part of throwing a `GradleException`, but that did not help.

Note that I use the `testsWithLeak` variable because I only want to throw this exception if the test did not already fail. A test may fail due to other assertions in which case I do not want to check for leaks (as the `GradleException` may mask the underlying assertion failure).

Also note that throwing the `GradleException` as part of the `afterTest` closure does not appear to fail the build.

How can I:

1. Fail a build when a test logs this message
2. Only throw this exception when the test did not otherwise fail
3. Ensure the build will correctly fail on subsequent attempts (without relying on commandline options)

Answer (score 1):

The test is considered up to date because the test inputs (the class files) and the test outputs (the xml report) have not changed since the previous run. You can do the following so that tests are never up to date

```
test {
   outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
   ... 
}
```

See

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I don't want to invalidate the test cache *all* the time -- only when a build fails for this reason. Is there a way I can mark them not as up to date as part of this failure sequence?

Comment: E.g., I would like to use something like `doNotCacheIf​`, but I'm not sure how to make it work with my `finalizedBy` logic.

Comment: You could throw the exception in a `doLast{...}` block of the test task instead of using a separate task

Comment: `doLast{...}` in the test task seemed to work, thank you! It's interesting that throwing an exception in `doLast{...}`, but not `afterTest{...}`, will change the build outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your `testsWithLeak` map will not persist between gradle invocations. I suggest you write to a file under `$buildDir` and add a `TaskOutputs.upToDateWhen {...}` predicate to check the file exists. Your `checkLeaks` tasks should also be driven by the file and not a project variable.

Eg:

```
test {
   ext {
      testsWithLeak = new java.util.Properties() 
      leakFile = file("$buildDir/testsWithLeak.props")
   } 
   outputs.upToDateWhen {!leakFile.exists()}
   onOutput {...}
   afterTest {...}
   doFirst {
      delete leakFile
   } 
   doLast {
      if (testsWithLeak) {
         leakFile.withWriter { testsWithLeak.store(it)}
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want the map to persist between invocations, I just want to ensure that tests are re-run on subsequent attempts. I would prefer to do this without touching the file system if possible.

Comment: This "subsequent attempts" you are talking about is obviously a subsequent Gradle invocation. As I said, if you want to persist state between invocations it's done via the file system. Or you could fail the task (which is ultimately recorded via the file system in Gradle's internal cache)